# Low image quality of TGaussianBlurEffect

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

After applying TGaussianBlurEffect in Delphi 10.3 (update 2), the resulting image has significantly lower quality comparing to Gaussian Blur in image editors and GBlur2.pas for example (albeit working slower). Is there a way to improve the quality of TGaussianBlurEffect?

Exmaples:
[image]

Comment: How do you compare images? Image editors have specifically written gauss-blur algorithms and I don't think `FMX` uses the one that `photoshop` uses.

Comment: In general Gaussian blur is not "magic smoothing", it has strict mathematical specification, so anyone might expect close results. But I can see that the only parameter is `BlurAmount` (not sigma or kernel size). Have you tried to change this parameter?

Comment: @Dima As MBo replied here, Gaussian Blur has strict specification, it should work the same way in photoshop and FMX. An example of the proper Gaussian Blur is implemented in GBlur2.pas (unknown author). Source code posted in another thread on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MBo BlurAmount controls only blurring depth. It doesn't have effect on quality.

Comment: Not sure that gaussian blur algorithm in my realisation produces *the same image* as Photoshop does. In any case, please, show us images which have been processed by gaussian blur and describe what *signficantly lower quality* is.

Comment: @Dima sorry for not providing examples from the very beginning, here they are.

Comment: Well, after inspecting image, I can bet that `TGaussianBlurEffect` is not a *real Gauss blur*, but *box blur*. Look [at this picture](https://imgur.com/DzFVlCg) that I made using [Box Blur algorithm](https://github.com/igorkandyba/different/blob/master/Blur/BoxBlur.pas). You can find result I got looking too close to your third image. So obvious reason of "bad" third image is applying `FMX` *pseudo-gauss blur* that made image less attractive then *honest* Gauss blur. But, suppose, I should mention, I have no source code of `FMX`, so my conclusion might be wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for another image blur library? Maybe https://github.com/graphics32/graphics32 is something? I noticed a blur unit (it containing ps GausianBlur routines) while digging into the library regarding another question on SO.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for clarifying. Indeed, FMX most probably implements Box Blur, and TGaussianBlurEffect class name appears to be misleading. Seems it can't be helped, will have to stick to good old GBlur2.pas at the moment.

Comment: @R.Hoek Nice finding! Checked some examples from the package, and seems it has proper Gaussian Blur implementation. But more importantly it renders the image much faster than GBlur2. Thank you!

Comment: It is better to late than never ;) Vlad, there is no need to use `GBlur2` algorithm. You can switch [to very fast blur solution](https://github.com/igorkandyba/different/blob/master/Blur/StackBlur.pas). Honestly, I didn't compare results and speed of both algorithms by myself, but I believe that `StackBlur` (link above) will be more speed optimized. P.S. personally I never worked with `Graphics32`, so it could be more optimized (or mmight not ;)) than `StackBlur`, but at least you have some directions to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Josef Svejk mentioned the Gaussian Blur in the FMX framework isn’t a true Gaussion blur, but a box blur.

When you want a genuine Gaussian blur, which is fast, you can use the library Graphics32 (https://github.com/graphics32/graphics32), which contains the unit `GR32_Blurs.pas` with several Gaussian blur routines.